# Using $this when not in object context in a Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, object, properties, static

I created a public static function in a controller and I need to access a class property which is set on the constructor. I normally use `$this->something` to access such class properties, but this time, I got this error:

> Using `$this` when not in object context

Here's the code:

```
public static function PayExecute() {
    $paymentId = Input::get('paymentId');
    $PayerID = Input::get('PayerID');

    $cont = $this->apiContext;
}
```

Comment: you cannot use $this on static functions

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need `$apiContext` be declared as static property, and you need use `static` of `self` keyword. Something like this:

```
class YourController extends BaseController
{
    private static $apiContext = '';

    public static function PayExecute()
    {
        $paymentId = Input::get('paymentId');
        $PayerID = Input::get('PayerID');

        $cont = static::$apiContext;
    }
}
```

BTW: Be aware about fact that `static` is late static binding.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot use "$this" in static methods.
You do have access to "self::" though, but remember that you cannot access methods / properties that require the current class to be instanciated.

Answer (score 3):

The source of this problem is the wrong instantiation of the Excel class.

Check your controller.

Wrong: `use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;`

Correct: `use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a non-static controller function (so `public function myFunc` instead of `public static myFunc`), but I forgot a line where I was calling the function statically (like `MyController::myFunc`).

Removing this line fixed the error.

Moral of the story: when your function uses `$this->something`, do not call the function statically :)

Answer (score 0):

kindly use **self::** instead of **$this->** if you are calling to the function which refers to the same function

```
public static function PayExecute() {
   $paymentId = Input::get('paymentId');
   $PayerID = Input::get('PayerID');

   $cont = self::apiContext;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to create new instance and then can access its property

```
public static function PayExecute() {
    $paymentId = Input::get('paymentId');
    $PayerID = Input::get('PayerID');

    $cont = (new static)->apiContext;
}
```